# How to calculate the total of price for product in Laravel blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I want to calculate the total price. How can I do it?

This is my blade code:

```
@foreach ($ventes as $value)       
    <td>{{ $value->produit->nom }}</td>                   
        <td>        
            {{ $value->quantitevendu }}</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            ({{$value->prix}})*{{$value->quantitevendu}}.euro
        </td>

        <td>
            ({{$value->prix}}).DH
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ $value->description }}
        </td>          
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

**It gives me results like this**:

(10)*2

(11)*4

(2)*1

**But I want results like this**:

20

44

2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did concatenation instead of multiplication. Try this:

```
@foreach ($ventes as $value)   
      <td>{{ $value->produit->nom }}</td>                   
        <td>

      {{ $value->quantitevendu }}</a>
     </td>
      <td>{{$value->prix * $value->quantitevendu}} .euro</td>

      <td>({{$value->prix}}).DH</td>
      <td>{{ $value->description }}</td>          
    </tr>
  @endforeach
```

I hope you get it the idea.

Comment: You are very welcome. I hope you are enjoying Laravel

Answer (score 1):

It's best practice to put heavy calculation within your Model. Laravel allow to create imaginary attributes event when they doesn't really exist
on your table. for that your can just define an attribute accessor in which you perform all your calculation like bellow

```
class Vente extends Model {

    public function getPrixTotalAttribute()
    {
        return $this->attributes['prix'] * $this->attributes['quantitevendu'];
    }
}
```

And in your view you will have just to do `{{ $value->prix_total}}`

Comment: Agreed. You should be doing things like calculating totals in your model, not the view.